# Bash script formatting issue while sending file as mail body

Tags: scripting, carriage-return, mailx

I need to send contents of a file as mail boy and i am using below command

```
cat filename.txt | tr -d \\r  | mailx -s "test"  abc@xyz.com
```

Below is content of file

this is first line
this second line
this is third line
this is fourth line

Below is what i am receiving over mail

this is fist line this is 
second line this is third
line this is fourth line

so there is problem with formatting.

I tried to use other options to send content of file as mail body like below . But they did not work.

cat filename.txt | mail -s test abc@xyz.com

So please help

thanks in advance.

After trying below command

[image]

Below is content of file

[image]

Below is what i received over mail

[image]

Comment: looks to me problem of carriage return only, could you please try `tr -d '\r' < filename.txt > temp && mv temp filename.txt; cat filename.txt | mailx -s "test"  abc@xyz.com` once and let us know then?

Comment: tried above but did not work :(

Comment: Could you please try `cat -v file` and see if your file has control M characters in it?

Comment: Yes it has control M character in it. I have checked as per your comment. But not sure what does it means.

Comment: Cool then command `tr -d '\r' < filename.txt > temp && mv temp filename.txt; cat filename.txt | mailx -s "test" abc@xyz.com` should work, didn't it work?

Comment: still same status , i have updated my question with screenshots. Please check.